# Заполнение массива путем ввода через Prompt

Tags: javascript

Как правильно при заполнении массива через `prompt`, если пользователь не ввел значение, выводить `prompt` до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет какое-то значение?

```
function addName() {
    var arrContainer = document.getElementById('array');

    var arr = []; // создаем массив
    for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {

        arr[i] = prompt('Введите любое имя', +i); // Заполняем массив
        if(arr[i] === null) { // если  нажимаем "Отмена"
            alert('Отмена');
            return;
        }

        if(arr[i] === '') { // если  имя не введено
            alert('Вы не указали имя');
            arr[i] = prompt('Введите любое имя'); 
        }
    }

    arrContainer.innerHTML = '';
    arrContainer.innerHTML = arr;

    console.log(arr); // Выводим массив целиком
}
```

Comment: так в прошлом же вопросе уже была решена проблема вызовом promt еще раз

Comment: Да, `return prompt(...);` И что такое `arrContainer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо бы ещё считать неудачные попытки, чтобы не замучить алёртами бедного юзера, который передумал вводить имена.

```js
function addName() {
  var arrContainer = document.getElementById('array')
    ,n     = 5  // число элементов массива
    ,max   = 3  // макс. число перезапросов
    ,att        // счётчик попыток
    ,i          // индекс элемента массива
    ,greet = '' // сообщение при запросе
    ,arr   = [] // создаем массив
  ;
  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for( att=0; att<max;) {
      greet = 'Введите любое имя №'+(i+1); 
      if(att++ > 0) greet += ' (попытка '+att+' из '+max+')';
      arr[i] = prompt( greet); // Заполняем массив
      if (null !== arr[i]  &&  arr[i].length) break;
      if(att === max) {
        alert("Ой, всё");
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  arrContainer.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
  return arr;
}

addName();
```

```html
<div id="array"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не притендую на красивый код, вот решение в лоб:

```
function addName() {
    var arrContainer = document.getElementById('array');
    var arr = []; // создаем массив
    for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        while(
          typeof (arr[i] = prompt('Введите любое имя №'+i)) != 'string' || arr[i].length == 0
        );
    }
    arrContainer.innerHTML = arr;
    console.log(arr); // Выводим массив целиком
}
```

Демо:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxdvOy

Кто разгадает фокус с `typeof`? :)

Comment: Ну typeof будет приводится к false в условии while, пока не будет равен строке или будет равен длине 0, а вот как это что while без тела - я не понимаю еще)

Comment: при отмене промпта вернется `null` и `typeof` не будет равен `string`